# jQuery selectors throw "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, typeerror

I am completely new to jQuery. I am writing a Tampermokey (latest version) script in Chromium (34.0.1847.116) using jQuery (latest version). I am getting many instances of jQuery selectors throwing

> `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

deep in jQuery's code when a query executes. Some examples:

```
$("body table[width='200']") ... ok
$("body").find("table[width='200']") ... TypeError
$("body").find("table") ... ok

$("th") ... ok
$("th:contains('text')") ... TypeError
```

and I could give many other examples. What could be happening here? I suppose jQuery is mature so there has to be something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Could be that your version of jQuery has been modified? Could be that some standard methods are overwritten. Could be a number of things, but nothing you've provided in the question would give any sort of indication of what's wrong.

Comment: And what the heck is Tampermonkey?

Comment: TamperMonkey lets you modify webpages on the fly http://tampermonkey.net/

Comment: Somehow, you have a function named `$` that is not returning an object with a method named `.find()`.  That makes it sound to me like you don't have jQuery installed (and something else has defined `$`) or something else has overridden the definition of `$` (often assigned to `document.querySelectorAll()` or something like that.  A basic debugging step would be to do `var x = $("body")` and then look at what `x` is in the debugger (examine it's properties and methods).

Comment: lol, ok. my version of jquery is not modified, im using latest as i said. $ _is_ a function that returns a object with a find method. like i said, the exception is thrown deep in jQuery code, find gets called just fine. and btw $ is jQuery's, $(...) returns a jQuery object.